# multi thread requesting in go and not getting high RPS

Tags: multithreading, go, http, request, client

I'm trying to write a multi thread client to test my server. when I use 2 goroutines everything is fine and I get 50k RPS and my CPU load is normal but when I create more than 2 the RPS drop down to 3K however my CPU load exceed. although when i run my client code multi times (for example run same code on 3 consol at same time) i get more RPS like 80k RPS.

here is my client side code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    requestURL := fmt.Sprintf("http://localhost:%d/home", 3333)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(4)
    req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, requestURL, nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("client: could not create request: %s\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    for i := 0; i < 4; i++ {
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            client := http.Client{
                Timeout: 30 * time.Second,
            }
            for {
                client.Do(req)
            }
        }()
    }
    wg.Wait()
}
```

and here is my server side code

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus"
    "github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus/promhttp"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "sync"
)

// log handling
func openLogFile(path string) (*os.File, error) {
    logFile, err := os.OpenFile(path, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE, 0644)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return logFile, nil
}

// variables of counter in metric
var okStatusCounter = prometheus.NewCounter(
    prometheus.CounterOpts{
        Name: "ok_request_count",
        Help: "Number of 200",
    },
)

func listener(serverLog *log.Logger) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        //metric 
        okStatusCounter.Inc()
        
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    }
}

func main() {
    //metric
    prometheus.MustRegister(okStatusCounter)

    //log handling
    fileSimpleServerLog, err := openLogFile("simpleServer/simpleServerLog.log")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    serverLog := log.New(fileSimpleServerLog, "[simple server]", log.LstdFlags|log.Lshortfile|log.Lmicroseconds)

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)

    //server:
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        mux := http.NewServeMux()
        mux.HandleFunc("/home", listener(serverLog))
        mux.Handle("/metrics", promhttp.Handler())
        server := http.Server{
            Addr:    fmt.Sprintf(":%d", 3333),
            Handler: mux,
        }
        if err := server.ListenAndServe(); err != nil {
            if !errors.Is(err, http.ErrServerClosed) {
                serverLog.Printf("error running http server: %s\n", err)
            }
        }
    }()
    wg.Wait()
}
```

at first I thought go may use one port for all of client connection but when I checked it out with netstat it was using multiple ports. I tried to search but I couldn't find any proper answer

I tried sync.Mutex :

```
var mu sync.Mutex
...
for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            client := http.Client{
                //Timeout: 30 * time.Second,
            }
            for {
                mu.Lock()
                _, err := client.Do(req)
                if err != nil {
                    clientLog.Printf("client: error making http request: %s\n", err)
                    os.Exit(1)
                }
                mu.Unlock()
            }
        }()
    }
    wg.Wait()
...
```

with change above I get 13k RPS and my CPU load is normal but that's not near enough at all

Comment: Modify your `client.Do()` call to check for, and log, errors. I suspect that will provide you with an answer (also read the [docs](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Client.Do) re closing the response).

Comment: I can't creat mote than 2 When I add error handler and I got`Get "http://localhost:3333/home": net/http: request canceled`

Comment: I cannot replicate your results - your code runs successfully for me (I did add an iteration limit). Note that, as mentioned in my first comment, not draining/closing the response body is likely to be having an impact (in my rough testing this doubled the speed with 4 goroutines; 4 goroutines ran around 30% faster than 2). Adding a mutex within the goroutine just prevents simultaneous requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you send requests to only one host, the default values of HTTP Transport are not suitable for you. It is better to set the parameters manually in your case:

```
t := http.DefaultTransport.(*http.Transport).Clone()
t.MaxIdleConns = 100
t.MaxConnsPerHost = 100
t.MaxIdleConnsPerHost = 100
    
httpClient = &http.Client{
  Timeout:   10 * time.Second,
  Transport: t,
}
```

For more information, you can read [here](https://www.loginradius.com/blog/engineering/tune-the-go-http-client-for-high-performance/).